# Asp.net Web application - ng-click not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, model-view-controller

ASP.NET MVC Web Application in VS 2015

I cannot figure out how to get this ng-click event to fire.  I am sure this is super simple but I can't figure it out.  Could someone explain what I am missing?

Views\Home\Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}


<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>File Uploader</h1>
    <p class="lead">Upload up to 5 files with a max file size of 12mb per file.</p>

    <!-- Upload -->
    <section class="row thematic-wrapper">
        <div ng-controller="Uploader" class="col-sm-12">
            <label class="lbl">Upload Documents >>>>  |</label>
            <button class="btn" ng-click="UploadFile" >
                Test Button
            </button>
        </div>
    </section>

</div>
```

Scripts\Controllers\Uploader.js:

```
'use strict'`enter code here`
$scope.UploadFile = function () {
    $log.log("Welcome to Uploader.js!")
}
```

I read the other posts here but I can't seem to get this to fire.  Do I need to install an AngularJS package?  I just want to post that log message to the console in chrome to get started.

Comment: upload file is function, you should call it `ng-click="UploadFile()"`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **`()`** next to the function

```
   <button class="btn" ng-click="UploadFile()" >
                Test Button
   </button>
```

Comment: have you added ng-controller?

Comment: It is in the HTML, do I need to add it in uploader.js too?